# What is the purpose of lambda when i call a function with an argument?

Tags: python, function, lambda, arguments, pyqt5

```
import  sys
import sqlite3
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets


class Pencere(QtWidgets.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):

        super().__init__()

        self.init_ui()

    def init_ui(self):

        self.a = 1
        self.button = QtWidgets.QPushButton()
        self.button1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton()
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.click)
        self.button1.clicked.connect(lambda: self.click1(a))

    def click(self):
        pass

    def click1(self,number):
        pass
```

Comment: Please explain your problem in the question text, not just the title.

Comment: The key word in @Barmar's comment is *explain*.

Comment: It *delays* the call of the function. `self.click1(a)` is called who you click the button, not when you call `connect`.

Comment: Note that `a` is a free variable, though, unrelated to either a local variable `a` in `init_ui` or an instance attribute `a`. You probably want `lambda a=self.a: self.click1(a)`. (`self.a` can probably be replaced with a local variable, though. `a = 1`, and `lambda a=a: self.click1(a)`

Comment: The purpose of lambda is the same here as anywhere else, to create an anonymous function. You don't have to use lambda, you could just use a function definition statement but some people find lambda more convenient

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Some time using lambda is necessary, especially if the signal has different or no arguments, less than what the function requires, or a default value has to be specified. In this case, it might necessary, as `clicked` has a checked parameter that would be used as the number argument, if not explicitly declared/changed in lambda.

Comment: @musicamante using `lambda` is **never necessary**. You can always use a regular function definition.

Comment: With "necessary" I don't mean that there are no other options, but that there are many situations for which creating specific regular explicit functions for single cases might result in unnecessary complications. For example, QActions have a checked argument that behaves in the same way as QAbstractButtons, and could trigger functions that accept different arguments. For the sake of simplicity over explicitness, in those cases lambdas can be better than writing multiple single function definitions that just behave slightly different than the actual function that could be called by lambda.

Comment: @musicamante what? How would that case necessitate writing multiple different function definition? You would do it exactly the same as with lambda, just using the statement. If you use lambda, you are still creating multiple different functions. That's *what lambda does*

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I'd say that there's a lot of difference between writing multiple 20-30-character anonymous lambdas (that are only used for a specific and isolated purpose) than writing the same number of functions as `def`. I know that conceptually there's no difference, the point is not about the resulting function, but the simplicity of the code avoiding unnecessary repetition of (possibly) single purpose functions that behave almost the same as the lambda would point to, just with different arguments, or finding more complex ways to do the same with less code and easier logic.

Comment: To clarify, a small example here: https://gist.github.com/MaurizioB/49338f3b6f83816a3638127056cff622 . This is just for the sake of the argument, I realize that here there's not *that much* of a difference between the lambda version and the others, but when one has very complex classes that rely on dozens of methods and has multiple situations for which an extra function has to be written just for a simple situation, it means adding possibly *a lot* of those functions (with presumably similar names, since they would do the same) that do not really improve readability nor functionality.

Comment: @musicamante I've responded in that gist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`self.button1.clicked.connect` takes as an argument a function which does not take any parameters (because that is how it will be called).  If you need it to call a function that *does* take a parameter (and you have the argument to be passed available), you can *make* that function with `lambda`.

Comment: Not exactly. [`clicked`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractbutton.html#clicked) has the `checked` parameter. It's usually only used for "checkable" buttons: QCheckBox, QRadioButton, QPushButton and QToolButton, but for the last two it is always False unless the `checkable` property is True. Also, to be more precise, `connect` takes as an argument a *reference to a callable*.